# Wix Bundle re-evaluate conditions before each package

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, burn

I'm working with a managed bootstrapper. In my bundle, I've one msi and one exe package (A big Winzip based self extractor installer), which must be installed before msi package. The msi package have to check if exe package was installed properly, because if installation of exe package fails or cancelled by user, msi should not proceed to installation. 
Detect conditions are only evaluated at the start of installation, not during or between the packages installations. Unfortunately, bootstrapper doesn't detect if exe package was failed or canceled, as it is returning 0 whenever user cancels the installation.
**Q: Is there any method/trick to re-evaluate the install condition, after exe package installation and just before msi package starts its installation, so that msi package InstallCondition would be evaluated?**

 BTW, I  can think of two solutions:

1. Evaluate detect conditions (write again) inside msi, but I want to
   inform user from bootstrapper UI.
2. To do something in my bootstrapper's, DetectPackageComplete() method, but I don't think so, that would be a proper way.

Here are my code segments:

```
<Bundle 
    Name            =   "$(var.ProductName)"
    Copyright       =   "$(var.CopyrightNote)"
    Version         =   "$(var.FileVersion)"
    Manufacturer    =   "$(var.Manufacturer)"
    IconSourceFile  =   "$(var.IconFile)"
    UpgradeCode     =   "$(var.UpdgradeCode)"
    AboutUrl        =   "$(var.AboutUrl)"
    Compressed      =   "yes"
    Tag             =   "VA"
  >

<util:RegistrySearchRef Id="PreReqRuntimeReg"/>

 <Chain>
      <RollbackBoundary Id="StartPoint"  />
      <PackageGroupRef Id = "Product_PreReq"  />

      <MsiPackage      Id                      = "MainProduct"
                       DisplayName             = "$(var.ProductName)"                       
                       DisplayInternalUI       = "no"
                       Cache                   = "yes"
                       Visible                 = "no"
                       Compressed              = "yes"
                       EnableFeatureSelection  = "yes"
                       SourceFile              = "$(var.MainProduct)"  
                       Vital                   = "yes"  
                       InstallCondition        = "PreReqRuntimeVersion=&quot;8.2&quot;"
       >
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
 <Fragment Id="Product_PreReqs">


    <util:RegistrySearch Id="PreReqRuntimeReg" 
        Variable="PreReqRuntimeVersion"                      
        Root="HKLM"
        Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\ThirdParty Compiler Runtime 2013"        
        Value="DisplayVersion" 
        Result="value" 
        Win64="yes" 
    />

    <PackageGroup Id="Product_PreReq">
      <ExePackage Id="PreReqRuntime2013"
        DisplayName="ThirdParty Compiler Runtime 2013"
        Description="ThirdParty Compiler Runtime 2013"
        Cache="no"
        Compressed="yes"
        PerMachine="yes"
        Permanent="yes"
        Vital="yes"
        SourceFile="D:\Pre-Reqs\Pre-Req2013_win64_installer.exe" 
        Protocol ="none"  
        DetectCondition="PreReqRuntimeVersion=&quot;8.2&quot;"
        InstallCondition="(NOT (PreReqRuntimeVersion=&quot;8.2&quot;))"

      />   
    </PackageGroup>

  </Fragment>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Up till now, I've found method 1 as the best option (however, still looking for more), i.e. **Evaluate detect conditions (write again) inside msi**. So if it fails, show the user a generic message about failure and give the link of log file to user.

However, still looking for some better option. In addition, I strongly feel the need to get msi errors, interpret them and shows the user a proper error message. 
Any suggestions, help are more than welcome. .. Thanks